# Invoke a Java program with windows program

Tags: java, swing

How to invoke any Java program when a application/program in windows is opened? For example when I start VLC media player, I want that a Java application starts before VLC media player starts.

Comment: What feature does this offer to the end user?

Comment: Its more helpful if you specify why you want this. Perhaps there are more convenient solutions than you are trying at this moment.

Comment: I want that a java applet/swing opens and asks for the password to open the program. Useful when I want some programs not to be accessed by anyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a batch file as this:

```
set echo off
java -jar "your java file path"
"your vlc path to run"
```

Comment: Once the batch file is written, make a shortcut to it and put it in your start menu. Then delete the vlc shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

You can either write a Batch-File that runs 'em both or write an application that monitors for the vlc.exe process and react on that.

Answer (score 0):

in other words: always use created batch to run vlc:
java yourApplication
vlc

or write an application, whitch periodicaly check all processes for given program. I know, there are some libs in C for Java to do this, but they are all platform dependent. If you are using Windows Vista or later, i think, you can exec, and parse result of tasklist command.